# Select wildcard in multidimensional list?

Tags: r, list, multidimensional-array

In R, I have a multidimensional list. I can access elements like:

```
results[["A1"]][["B2"]][["C1"]]
```

Of course, the output of the above statement is also a list.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
results[["A1"]][[*]][["C1"]]
```

or

```
results[["A1"]][[,]][["C1"]]
```

My desired output would be one big list, which is the concatenation of the lists for each value (e.g., "B1", "B2", ...) in the second dimension.

Is something like this possible? I know that I can iterate over the desired dimension:

```
for (i in 1:length(results[["A1"]])){
    output = c(output, results[["A1"]][[i]][["C1"]]
}
```

but I was wondering if there's anything cleaner? Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: Since I don't have sample data in front of me, I can't be sure of what you're starting with or ending with... but take a look at `lapply` and `unlist` with `recursive=FALSE`.  Those two should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't know if you still want them in list but converting them to a dataframe with do.call("rbind",list) and then subsetting the groups is much easier.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, this worked for me. Thanks! I ended up using something like `unlist(lapply(results[["A1"]], FUN=function(x){x[["C1"]]}), recursive=F)`

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
sapply( sapply(results[["A1]], "[[", TRUE), "[[", "C1"")
```

The generalization to a fourth level for a specific index name "D" would just be:

```
sapply( sapply( sapply(results[["A1"]], "[[", TRUE), "[[", "C1"), "[[", "D")
```

Reading from the inside out, as one needs to do with nested function calls,  all of sublists of the `results$A1` values are collected and then processed to construct a list of only those with "C1" names, and then that reduced list is further extracted from to yield values of the form `results$A1$all-wildcards$C1$D`. Given the fact that the "[[" function will evaluate its argument you could have offer an unquoted object that had multiple values if they were valid list names at the appropriate level of indexing.

Comment: This almost works. In my real dataset, I actually have two dimensions after the wildcard dimension, i.e., [["C1"]][["D1"]]. How would the syntax look for that?