# Extracting information from multi-level lists - R

Tags: r, list, wildcard, multi-level

I have output from a model written to a multilevel list. Essentially, there are 5 variables, and the list is constructed so that results to each scenario are identified by the variable values in that scenario. So the results of a run with K=0.5, C=0.9, V=0.5, R=0.25 and RV = 0 can be accessed by

```
results$`K=0.05`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Below is an example of how the full output might look:

```
results
$`K=0.05`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.9`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.05`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.05`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE




$`K=0.05`$`C=0.91`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.05`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.05`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE




$`K=0.05`$`C=0.92`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.05`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.05`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.05`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE





$`K=0.1`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.9`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.1`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.1`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE




$`K=0.1`$`C=0.91`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.1`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.1`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE




$`K=0.1`$`C=0.92`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.1`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.1`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.1`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE





$`K=0.15`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.9`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.15`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.15`$`C=0.9`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE




$`K=0.15`$`C=0.91`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.15`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.15`$`C=0.91`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE




$`K=0.15`$`C=0.92`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`
$`K=0.15`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0`
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.15`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.05`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$`K=0.15`$`C=0.92`$`V=0.5`$`R=0.25`$`RV=0.1`
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

For analysis, I'd like to be able extract results from all scenarios with specific variable values. For example, I'd like to extract the results of scenarios with C = 0.92 and RV = 0.1 (or any combination, really).

Something like:

```
results$*$'C=0.92'$*$*$'RV=0.1'
```

or

```
results[*]['C=0.92'][*][*]['RV=0.1']
```

I read a similar question regarding [wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432867/select-wildcard-in-multidimensional-list), which I don't think R utilizes, that didn't quite get where I needed it to go. Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should be storing your data in a data frame or some such.  I understand that the recursive structure is convenient when you're running tests in loops, but still.  Fortunately there is a function that can do the translation:

```
lst <- list(a=list(b=list(c0=list(d0=1:3, e0=4:6), c1=list(d1=7:9, e1=10:12))))
library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(lst)
subset(DF, grepl("1", L4))  # now we can use regular expressions against each list level
```

Produces:

```
   value L4 L3 L2 L1
7      7 d1 c1  b  a
8      8 d1 c1  b  a
9      9 d1 c1  b  a
10    10 e1 c1  b  a
11    11 e1 c1  b  a
12    12 e1 c1  b  a
```

You may want to look at `DF` to see what I'm doing with the subset.

Comment: This may help - however, I also have similar output where instead of vectors of logicals (as above), each list element is a matrix. I'll give it a shot and see what melt() would do in that instance... but could be a bit messy. That said, for what I listed above, your solution is elegant. +1

Comment: After trying it with other output, I think this is the way to go. Thanks for your help! Storing the output in lists during the loop is simplest, but converting to a melted dataframe makes life much easier in analysis. Thanks!